# Intuition behind the flow of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry

**Lemma :** Let $X$ be a smooth vector field on a a smooth manifold $M$.

For all $m\in M,$ there exists $a_m$ and $b_m$ in $\mathbb R \cup\{\pm \infty\}$ and a smooth curve $c_m :]a_m,b_m[ \rightarrow M$ such that :

1. $0 \in ]a_m,b_m[$ and $c_m(0)=m$;
2. $c_m$ is an integral curve of $X$;
3. If $\mu :]c,d[\rightarrow M$ is a smooth curve satisfying $1.$ and $2.$, then $]c,d[ \subset ]a_m,b_m[$ and $\mu=c_{m{|]c,d[}}.$

---

Now we define fot all $m\in M$ and $t\in \mathbb R$ the set $$\mathcal D_t=\{m\in M/ t\in ]a_m,b_m[\}$$
and the application $$\theta_t :\mathcal D_t \rightarrow M : \theta_t(m)=c_m(t),$$
and also $$\mathcal D(X)=\{(t,m)\in \mathbb R\times M / t\in]a_m,b_m[\}$$
and finally the application $$\theta : \mathcal D(x) \rightarrow M : \theta(t,x)=\theta_t(x)$$.
$\theta$ is called the flow of $X$.

---

I can't visualize the sets $\mathcal D_t, \mathcal D(X)$ and the flow of $X$ and what's the intuition behind all this ? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The expression $\theta_t(x)$ simply denotes the point where you end up if you start at $x$ and “follow the flow” for $t$ units of time. That is, at each instant you go with the velocity that the vector field (at the point where you happen to be at that instant) tells you to go. That is, you follow the integral curve through $x$.

For some vector fields and some starting points, it may happen (if the manifold is not compact) that you “go off to infinity” in finite time, so that $\theta_t(x)$ is not defined for all $t$ but only in some interval around $t=0$. The set $\mathcal{D}$ is just the set of pairs $(t,x)$ such that $\theta_t(x)$ is defined.

Comment: Thanks You for your answer, but to be honest I don't understand it yet, so can you please give me an example, or explain more, I have a trouble now to visualize $\theta_t(x)$ ?

Comment: Ok, do you know what in integral curve is, to begin with?

Comment: Yes I know it,  it's a amooth curve $c :J\rightarrow M $ such that $c'(t)=X(c(t)),$ for all $t\in J$.

Comment: Good. And you know that through a given point $x$, there is a unique integral curve $c(t)$ such that $c(0)=x$?

Comment: Yes, it's a consequence of the lemma above. Isn't it?

Comment: Exactly! So if you're given a point $x$, you have that curve $c$ (with its maximal interval of existence $J$), and if you're also given a number $t \in J$, you can compute the point $c(t)$. That point is (by definition) called $\theta_t(x)$. In other words, it's where you end up after $t$ units of time, if you start at $x$ and follow the integral curve starting there.

Comment: So it's the position where you will arrive after $ t$ moments? I think I understand it now

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thanks you so much Sir.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help.